# How to get delegate name inside delegated method?

Tags: c#, delegates

How to get delegate name inside delegated method?

Here is my program for testing:

```
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        public Action action;

        void real()
        {
            // I hoped it would output "action" here, but it was "real"
            Console.WriteLine(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        }

        public Program()
        {
            action = real;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program pr = new Program();
            pr.action();
        }
    }
}
```

So how can I get the name of delegate  `action` instead of method `read`?

I've tried `MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()`, but it didn't work.

Comment: `action` is delegate not the method, `real` is the delegate method.

Comment: From `void DoAction(Action actionParam)`, should it give `action` or `actionParam` ?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23990297/)

Comment: @Hassan Nisar, thanks for correction, I'll update the description.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, Sorry but I don't understand what you mean, could you add some details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program pr = new Program();
    Action tempName1 = pr.action;
    Action tempName2 = tempName1;

    //pr.action();
    tempName2();
}
```

Which name would you like to get? tempName1, tempName2, pr.action or just action?

From these choices it follows that you can't get an unambiguous variable name.

Comment: Thanks! Can I get tempName2 in this case?

Comment: No. <!-- ...(filler)... -->