# Application_DispatcherUnhandledException question

Tags: c#, exception, app.xaml

```
private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
MessageBox.Show($"e.Exception?.Message}\n*********\n*e.Exception?.Data.ToString()}**********{e.Exception.StackTrace}");
         e.Handled = true;
}
```

I use the above code in App.xaml.cs to catch any error unhandled in my code.
If the Message would be : An item with the same key has already been added.
because I tried to insert an existing key in a dictionary, how would I know which  dictionary it was? 
Is that somewhere in e ?
thanks
Frank

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the variable name for NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442419/getting-the-variable-name-for-nullreferenceexception)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: you would not.

CLR does not store the names of variables elsewhere. The explanation is given here: [Getting the variable name for NullReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442419/getting-the-variable-name-for-nullreferenceexception).

But you can inspect `e.data` object, which has `Keys` and `Values` properties, so you can *guess* which instance cas has this values.

Also, you can get information about source code line where exception was thrown: [How to get the name of the method that caused the exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598255/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-method-that-caused-the-exception)