# C# get variable name of an object in it's constructor

Tags: c#, variables, expression

I'm creating a bunch of string variables, which are to be used to store the value of the variable name itself.
e.g

```
string name = "name";
string number="number;
```

but as the list gets long, it becomes tedious to repetitively typing everything, so I made a class that just holds string data, and let the constructor to do the dirty work. e.g

```
class Data
{
public Data()
{
//pseudo code here:
name = NameOfTheVariable(this);
}
public string name {get;set;}    
}
```

So the ideal output would be something like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
//Declare an object here, the constructor will automatically assign the 
//variable name to the property.
 Data number = new Data();
 Console.WriteLine(number.name);
}
```

The output would be: "number", which is the variable name itself.

I did try to use MemberExpression mentioned in this post: [get name of a variable or parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801624/get-name-of-a-variable-or-parameter)

But the function doesn't take the keyword "this" as an valid argument.
so I cannot use the function provided in that post, eg:

```
class Data
{
public Data()
{
//This line will not work
name= MemberInfoGetting.GetMemberName(() => this);
}
public string name{get;set;}

}
```

Anybody know how I could solve this problem?

Comment: This is kinda complicated and weird way. You should create static class and declare your variables as static fields there.

Comment: I am wondering what you need this for? You can get variable/property names through reflection. But that's kinda slow. Also, in recent versions (not sure when it was introduced exactly) of c# there is `nameof()` ...

Comment: So you are working with C# version where `nameof` is not available?

Comment: @HenkHolterman `string name = nameof(name);` works fine for me.

Comment: Rerlated: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23959398/

Comment: There's so much here I don't understand. First, why is you class not a `static` class? Second, why do you even _have_ this class? Wouldn't a table of string resources in the assembly be better? Third, why can't you just declare each property as e.g. `public string Name { get; } = nameof(Name);`? If that's really too much typing, I guess you could use reflection, to enumerate all of the class's properties and for any of the `string` type, set the value to the property's name. What _specifically_ are you haven't trouble with here?

Comment: _"which is what the OP seems to want"_ - Exactly this is pretty *un*clear at least to me. @HenkHolterman I am not even sure if OP *means* "variable" when they say "variable" ...

Comment: What about a static class which holds all your variables, and at runtime you iterate through them (reflection) and initialize them, and possibly passing them to some constructor?

Comment: @C.Da do it the way you want is not possible, so you have to implement any of alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

```
Data number = new Data();
Console.WriteLine(number.name);
```

In C# 6.0 and above that would be:

```
SomeNumberClass number = new SomeNumberClass();
Console.WriteLine(nameof(number));
```

The solution for Pre-C# 6 you linked would work accordingly, you just would not write `nameof` but use a static method instead:

```
SomeNumberClass number = new SomeNumberClass();
Console.WriteLine(MemberInfoGetting.GetMemberName(() => number));
```

Comment: but if i wanna do it in the constructor, i can't assign variable name as value because i cannot use 'this' keyword in the argument

Comment: @C.Da You don't do this in the CTOR of `Data`. I just left Data here because you used it in your examples. The last snippet would just be called instead of the line `Console.WriteLine(nameof(number));` when using a C# version prior to C# 6.0.